# SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 inside mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which are having PK and FK relationship as shown below.

### **QUERY**

```
CREATE TABLE `sector_tab` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`code` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `ticker_tab` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`company_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`sector_num` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `ind_sector_number` (`sector_num`),
CONSTRAINT `ticker_tab_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sector_num`) 
REFERENCES `sector_tab` (`code`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4096 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now when i want to truncate 'sector_tab' table but because of PK-FK relationship i am getting error, so I want to disable it with SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 but i am not able to do but when i mentioned FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 inside procedure as shown below and running it its working. How come this happends?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_FK_diable`()<br>
BEGIN

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE sector_tab;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;<br>
END
```

I am doing from Mysql Query Browser 1.1

Comment: **Include** error messages. Don't just say "it's not working". This isn't how you ask for help, just include every possible info for other people to help you.

Comment: "Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`web`.`ticker_tab`, CONSTRAINT `ticker_tab_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sector_num`) REFERENCES `web`.`sector_tab` (`code`))" is the error i am getting when i am trying to truncate 'sector_tab' table and i know why this error is showing but my question is how come its executing through procedure, please read the question i asked carefully.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a procedure? Just issue a query that does `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; TRUNCATE TABLE sector_TAB; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;` and that's it. If you can't issue everything in 1 query, perform 3 queries.

Comment: I used the same query but FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is not disabling may be privileges issue i am not sure, if i have limited privileges then how this works inside procedure.

Comment: these are the privileges i am having GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES,
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE,
EVENT, TRIGGER

Answer (score 1):

```
delimiter $
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_FK_diable()
BEGIN

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE sector_tab;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
END
$
```